# Is there a way to make a textbox accept only arabic characters in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I need to set a validation to a textbox that can only accept arabic characters

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate(evt) {
var theEvent = evt || window.event;
var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
key = String.fromCharCode(key);
var regex;
 regex = /[دجحخ هعغفقثصضذطكمنتالبيسشظزوةىلارؤءئإلإلأأ؟آلآ]|\.|\s/;

if (!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
}
}
```

Comment: This is pure Javascript function which called with onkeypress="validate(event,'ar')"  with input control, it is easy to figure it out using angular and typescript